# rmagick is there a way to convert image in memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

From `Rmagick` guide:

Converting an image to another format

Converting an image to another format is as simple as writing the
 image to a file.

ImageMagick uses the output filename `suffix (".jpg"
 for JPEG, ".gif" for GIF, for example)` or `prefix ("ps:" for
 PostScript, for example)` to determine the format of the output image.

Is there a way to convert image in memory?

Comment: In use the image is held in one of a few possible "Image Magick" formats, and the concept of converting it is not that clear cut. Are you basically wanting to avoid writing the contents to disk, so you can HTTP serve a specific image type from memory?

Comment: Yes, I would like to avoid writing to disk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
# assuming you have an image
# img = Magick::Image.new( 100, 100 )
img = Magick::Image.from_blob( img.to_blob { self.format = "png" } )
```

Source: [RMagick Docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#to_blob)

Here's an example on how to [give it to the user](http://macdiggs.com/2007/03/08/rmagickrvg-outputting-an-inline-image/)

```
image.format = "png"
send_data image.to_blob,
    :filename => "woohoo.png",
    :disposition => 'inline',
    :quality => 90,
    :type => 'image/png'
```