# Use convert method of imagemagick in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I used `convert /home/icicle/Desktop/images_284.tif /home/icicle/Desktop/images_284.jpg`  from my terminal and it converted the image to jpg format.
But when I used it in my application it gave me the error `NoMethodError - undefined method`convert' for #:`

How can I use the convert method in my ruby on rails application?

Comment: `convert` is a utility, not a ruby method. You'll need to use an API like [RMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/), or pass the command to [system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy looks like answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426622/159995.

Or you can just use `system('convert /home/icicle/Desktop/images_284.tif /home/icicle/Desktop/images_284.jpg')`

Comment: Thanks @Hector ... system('convert /home/icicle/Desktop/images_284.tif /home/icicle/Desktop/images_284.jpg') worked